# How to delete question permanently

Tags: support, post-ban, self-delete

Some of my questions weren't important and also my fault. They were downvoted. Even, no expected answer.

So, I've tried Google and found the answers were quite easy.

I'm also blocked from questioning because of the previous answered questions.

I've tried to delete them but they don't disappear / are not deleted permanently.

What can I do now? Those questions can't be edited.
**How to get the question opportunity again?**

For instance, I want to delete this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353377/making-uppercase-of-word-in-regexp-jquery-javascript) .

Comment: i've lost track of what the question is...

Comment: @L_Church I'm not Englishman. Can you please tell easily

Comment: Deleting the questions won't help. Deleted questions still count against the question ban. Sorry, I'm afraid that we can't really help you.

Comment: You accepted an answer to your linked question.  Removing the question at this point would be unfair to the user who spent their time, to answer your question.  There are numerous ways to improve the linked question.  It appears you believe StackOverflow is a forum.  Some advice, don't apologize for your lack of English skills, embrace your lack of knowledge and do your best.  When presented with feedback on how to improve your questions, embrace that feedback, and follow it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are [question-banned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). Deleting low-rated questions won't help - it will rather make the situation worse (deleting questions also rates negatively, and deleted question still count for being question-banned).

I can I recommend that you try to improve your existing questions (**INSTEAD** of deleting them). Failing that you will (after 6 months) get the opportunity to ask **ONE** question - if that question is well-received you can continue asking, if not, the ban is reinstated.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is uneditable. If I edit them the point/topic won't change

Comment: @AAShakil You must **not** change the entire content of the question (or the answer won't make any more sense). Try to improve the formatting, presentation - anything to make any potential other user that have similar issues benefit more from your question. If you cannot edit your question at all, then I'm out of ideas and can only refer you to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @CharonX To be honest... If a question is just bad, then it's better to **not** edit it. Edits will just push those questions to the front page, giving them more attention and more downvotes. I don't like to say it, but sometimes the best option is just to leave these questions alone, and hope nobody will notice them anymore.

Comment: @AAShakil I have considered (and tried) to copyedit / improve the question you linked to, but recalling S.L. Barth's comment I'm uncertain whether it would not be better to let it rest instead.

Comment: @charonx but it'll get downvote. You could see I've more like this. When I was noob at SO I've done this mistake.

Comment: @AAShakil yeah, that's why I decided to not edit it in the end. Sorry that I can't help you out. :(